# Disable object, during busy cursor showing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textfield, busy-cursor

I've a complex text field which I can embed types of font within it. When I try to choose a specific font through the Dropdownlist, I'll show the busy cursor till font embeds inside the text field completely.

I want to disable my text field based on showing busy cursor... I mean when the busy cursor is showing disable the text filed and after disappearing that, just enabled text field again. 
How can I do that?
Is there any specific listener for that or what?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share some code

Comment: How are you embedding the fonts in the text fields?

Comment: I'm sure indeed sharing my codes was best and helpful guys, But somwhow I could not share it. sorry for this :( In total I'm using MVC pattern in my project and fonts are embedding in the text filed based on interaction of multiple classes. (One of reasons I was not able to share my codes here)... Anyway tanx for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you share some code it would be easier to answer. Or just try this, just check the condition over there there is a method called useHandCursor or useBusyCursor. where you used to show that method. just check that condition and disable that. I hope it works.

Comment: Somehow I used your suggested way my friend, of course with some changes based of my project coding. tanx for your relpy